# getScanResults with Android 6.0 returns empty List

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-wifi

`getScanResults` return an empty `list`.

Tested on `Android 6.0` phone with Location enabled. Is there anything i miss/error?
Following is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WifiManager mainWifiObj;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
    registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

}

public void onButClicked(View view){
    mainWifiObj.startScan();
}

class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        List<ScanResult> wifiList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
        String text = String.valueOf(wifiList.size());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

I have include permission as suggested on other posts as well.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your app has the location permission enabled? Android 6 introduced inAPP permission which means that when you are installing the app, there is no question about permissions. The permissions is requesting when needed in runtime. But if you check **Settings -> Applications -> (YOUR APP) -> Permissions** and the location permission is off, then you are not allowed to get location.